# A Question Regards Operators on Inner-Product Spaces, involving $\epsilon$

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a complex inner product space. Suppose $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is self-adjoint, $\lambda\in F$, and $\varepsilon>0$. Prove that if there exists $v\in V$ such that $\|v\|=1$ and

$$\|Tv-\lambda v\|<\varepsilon$$

then $T$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda'$ such that $|\lambda-\lambda'|<\varepsilon$.

I admit I don't know how to approach the question since I don't quite understand the question intuitively, it seems $\varepsilon$ involve the definition of limit

Comment: by contradiction?Im just guessing...

Comment: When you write $\varepsilon>0$ but put ">0" _outside_ the math environment and only $\varepsilon$ _inside_ it, you get a mismatch in font sizes and lack of proper spacing, thus: $\varepsilon$>0.  I changed it to $\varepsilon>0$.  (I also took the liberty of changing $\epsilon$ to $\varepsilon$, but perhaps that is a matter of taste.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: What is $V$ in this question?

Comment: This follows if you expand $v$ in terms of an ONB consisting of eigenvectors.

Comment: @NateEldredge I've updated the question now

Comment: Is $V$ finite-dimensional?  Is $T$ continuous?

Comment: @NateEldredge $V$ is finite, but the question doesn't say anything about T except T is a self adjoint operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ is self adjoint thus is has an orthonormal basis $ \{v_1 , ..., v_n\} $ of eigenvectors. Let $ \lambda_1 , ..., \lambda_n $ the eigenvalues respect to the basis. Denote $v=\sum\limits _{i=1}^{n}a_i v_i $. Let $\lambda^{'} $ be the eigevalue that makes $|\lambda_i -\lambda|$ minimal. Thus $$ \varepsilon^2 > \langle Tv-\lambda v,  Tv-\lambda v \rangle =
\langle \sum a_i \lambda_i v_i - \sum a_i \lambda v_i,\sum a_i \lambda_i v_i - \sum a_i \lambda v_i\rangle=\langle \sum a_i(\lambda_i-\lambda)v_i, \sum a_i(\lambda_i-\lambda)v_i\rangle =\sum |a_i|^2|\lambda_i-\lambda|^2\geq |\lambda-\lambda ^{'}|^2\sum |a_i|^2= \\|\lambda-\lambda ^{'}|^2 \cdot||v||= |\lambda-\lambda ^{'}|^2$$
and we are done.